# Operar con valores que están en filas no consecutivas?

Tags: r, datatables, date, dataframe, operador

El problema que tengo es sencillo, tengo datos por meses y quiero saber el incremento de un mes comparado con el mismo mes el año anterior.

```
datos <- data.table(c("marzo.2019","Junio.2019","Sep2019", "Dic2019","marzo.2020","Junio.2020","Sep2020", "Dic2020","marzo.2021","Junio.2021","Sep2021", "Dic2021"),ceiling(runif(12)*10000))

colnames(datos) <- c("Fecha","datos")
```

Me gustaria crear una columna que sea dividir marzo.2020/marzo.2019 y que lo haga para todas.
Sinceramente no se como afrontar este problema con R.

Un saludo,

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo y claro al menos para mí, es hacer un `left join` de forma que, relacionemos un fila con la que le corresponde del año anterior. Para hacer esto lo primero es convertir los textos en variables para mes y año:

```
datos[, "Year" := as.numeric(substr(Fecha,nchar(Fecha)-(4-1),nchar(Fecha)))]
datos[, "Mes" :=  substr(Fecha,1,nchar(Fecha) - 4)]
datos[, "YearPrev" := Year - 1]
datos

         Fecha datos Year    Mes YearPrev
 1: marzo.2019  8160 2019 marzo.     2018
 2: Junio.2019  6473 2019 Junio.     2018
 3:    Sep2019  1204 2019    Sep     2018
 4:    Dic2019  5439 2019    Dic     2018
 5: marzo.2020  1848 2020 marzo.     2019
 6: Junio.2020  6358 2020 Junio.     2019
 7:    Sep2020   743 2020    Sep     2019
 8:    Dic2020   420 2020    Dic     2019
 9: marzo.2021  3704 2021 marzo.     2020
10: Junio.2021  7573 2021 Junio.     2020
11:    Sep2021    19 2021    Sep     2020
12:    Dic2021  1598 2021    Dic     2020
```

Teniendo una columna que nos indica el año anterior de cada fila, procedemos a hacer un `left join`

```
merge(x=datos, 
      y=datos, 
      by.x=c("YearPrev", "Mes"), 
      by.y=c("Year", "Mes"), 
      all.x = TRUE,
      suffixes = c("", "_prev"))[, c("Fecha", "datos", "datos_prev")] -> -> datos.new
```

Y ahora que tenemos el valor actual y el anterior en cada fila solo resta dividir:

```
datos.new[, result := datos / datos_prev]
datos.new

         Fecha datos datos_prev     result
 1:    Dic2019  5439         NA         NA
 2: Junio.2019  6473         NA         NA
 3:    Sep2019  1204         NA         NA
 4: marzo.2019  8160         NA         NA
 5:    Dic2020   420       5439 0.07722008
 6: Junio.2020  6358       6473 0.98223389
 7:    Sep2020   743       1204 0.61710963
 8: marzo.2020  1848       8160 0.22647059
 9:    Dic2021  1598        420 3.80476190
10: Junio.2021  7573       6358 1.19109783
11:    Sep2021    19        743 0.02557201
12: marzo.2021  3704       1848 2.00432900
```